# Working through ES6 Katas, extending promises

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to extend these two promises:

```
   it('using `class X extends Promise{}` is possible', function() {
  class MyPromise extends Promise {
    constructor()
    {
      super();
    }
  };
  const mypromise = new MyPromise((resolve) => resolve());

  promise
    .then(() => done())
    .catch(e => done(new Error('Expected to resolve, but failed with: ' + e)));
});

it('must call `super()` in the constructor if it wants to inherit/specialize the behavior', function() {
  class ResolvingPromise extends Promise {
    constructor() {
    super();
    }}

  return new ResolvingPromise((resolve) => resolve());
});

});
```

and am receiving this error:

"Constructor Promise requires 'new'"

I'm using 'new', so what does it want from me?

Comment: Your code won't pass `(resolve) => resolve()` argument to parent `Promise` constructor. You should declare your constructors using `constructor(...args) { super(...args); }`. I don't know if that gets rid of the message, but at least you'll pass the closure to promise.

Comment: Are you using a transpiler or are you executing this in an actual ES6 environment?

Comment: What is the correct answer for "must call `super()` in the constructor if it wants to inherit/specialize the behavior"?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be the answer

```
it('must call `super()` in the constructor if it wants to inherit/specialize the behavior', function() {
      class ResolvingPromise extends Promise {
        constructor(resolve) {
          super(resolve);
        }
      }

      return new ResolvingPromise((resolve) => resolve());
    });
```

Comment: give me that error TypeError: Method Promise.prototype.then called on incompatible receiver #<MyPromise>

Comment: @ÁlvaroTouzón The error may happen if the class was transpiled. It should be real ES6 class in order to work.

Answer (score 1):

```
it('using `class X extends Promise{}` is possible', function() {
      class MyPromise extends Promise {}
      const promise = new MyPromise((resolve, reject) => {})

      promise
        .then(() => done())
        .catch(e => done(new Error('Expected to resolve, but failed with: ' + e)));
    });
```

Comment: using this solition give me that error TypeError: Method Promise.prototype.then called on incompatible receiver #<ResolvingPromise>